# URI de ruta en laravel similar a otra

Tags: php, laravel, rutas

Tengo un problema con las rutas en laravel, tengo un controlador el cual llamo a todos sus métodos en la ruta de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::resource("ficha_estudiantes", FichaEstudianteController::class);
```

Ahora bien, cree un nuevo método en ese controlador y necesito asignarle una ruta, y lo hice de la siguiente forma.

```
Route::get("ficha_estudiantes/crear_acudiente", [FichaEstudianteController::class, "create_acudiente"])->name("ficha_estudiantes.create_acudiente");
```

El problema es que esta ultima ruta no me funciona con esa URI si la cambio por ejemplo a /crear_acudiente si pero con el prefijo de ficha_estudiantes no me funciona.

Como podría solucionarlo ? Gracias

Comment: hola buenas , probaste colocando tu ruta "ficha_estudiantes/crear_acudiente" sobre la ruta resource?

Comment: puede ver tus rutas en la consola con el comando : `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @sergio como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Posicionate en la carpeta de tu proyecto, y en la consola de windows (CMD, Powershell o WSL) escribe `php artisan route:list`

Comment: la ruta si sale, la pregunta es como agregarla dentro de la misma ruta resource?

Comment: el problema se basa en que laravel lee la parte de la ruta `crear_acudiente` como un parametro de las rutas generadas en resource, por ende se debe escribir sobre la ruta sobre las rutas resource para que no genere conflicto.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer respecto a este problema es agregar tu ruta

```
Route::get("ficha_estudiantes/crear_acudiente", [FichaEstudianteController::class, "create_acudiente"])->name("ficha_estudiantes.create_acudiente");
```

sobre la ruta resource, aqui un ejemplo:

```
//routes/web.php

Route::get("ficha_estudiantes/crear_acudiente", [FichaEstudianteController::class, "create_acudiente"])->name("ficha_estudiantes.create_acudiente");
//y luego tu ruta resource
Route::resource("ficha_estudiantes", FichaEstudianteController::class);
```